# Interface groups

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, interface

I started to study Linux networking system (especially Ubuntu) lately.

I got interface info by command `ip a` like this:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

What I want to ask is the `group default` part.
<strike>The `group` seems to mean interface groups described at [here](https://man.cx/ifconfig(1)#heading7) .</strike>
(This is incorrect at least the link. Thank you [A.B.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/251756/a-b))

What does 'group default' exactly mean?
I want to understand it for studying.

Please let me know if you have any info.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but you are mistaken. ifconfig is an obsolete command which should never be consulted for any reference. interface group is (partly) defined there: https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/iproute2/ip-link.8.en.html#group~2 and is not related to IP addresses at all. You should revise your question. Probably waiving the understanding of the definition, and also the main thing to add in your question is: what is the problem you want to solve. Not simply how, but why. A concrete example with interfaces and addresses (since your problem is apparently about IP addresses) would help.

Comment: Actually the link you show appears to be about the ifconfig command of an other OS than Linux (there's no "plumb" or "addif" on Linux): probably Solaris.

Comment: Thank you for correcting.

Comment: And sorry for my silly post.
I want to understand what 'group default' exactly means for studying.

Comment: I modified my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to tag an interface with a group value. By default this value is 0 and is shown as "default" because it's resolved from the file [`/etc/iproute2/group`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/tree/etc/iproute2/group?h=v5.15.0) which usually includes (only) this:

> ```
> # device group names
> 0 default
> ```

One can add more entries in this file to use and display words (eg: `blue`) instead of numbers (eg: `1`).

The role of this group value is to group interfaces together for some special operations by assigning them the same value (group 0 as the default probably won't allow some of these operations).

Below's an example if one want to bring up and then delete one-shot a group of virtual interfaces (say some are *dummy*, other *veth* and yet other *bridges*). It's important to use the `group` keyword before the `type` because these can introduce different uses of the same keyword. This example about deletion is only for virtual interfaces but any interface including real can of course be assigned a group value too.

at creation (except here for `bridgeg1`):

```
ip link add name dummyg1 group 1 type dummy
ip link add name vethg1 group 1 type veth
ip link add name bridgeg1 type bridge
```

An interface can have its [group changed later](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/iproute2/ip-link.8.en.html#group%7E2) too:

```
ip link set dev bridgeg1 group 1
```

display interfaces tagged with group 1:

```
# ip -o link show group 1
3: dummyg1: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group 1 qlen 1000\    link/ether 1a:c8:19:3b:f5:e8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: veth0@vethg1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group 1 qlen 1000\    link/ether 02:6e:66:bb:69:e8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: vethg1@veth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group 1 qlen 1000\    link/ether 6e:22:d1:3d:5c:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: bridgeg1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group 1 qlen 1000\    link/ether 7e:23:0c:7c:f5:18 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

[Set them all](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/iproute2/ip-link.8.en.html#group%7E2) up at once:

```
ip link set group 1 up
```

[deletion of interfaces](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/iproute2/ip-link.8.en.html#group) tagged group 1:

```
# ip -o link delete group 1
```

they're gone:

```
# ip -o link show 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000\    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: ip6tnl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1452 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000\    link/tunnel6 :: brd :: permaddr 2001:db8:1234::
```

There are probably other uses across the whole network stack of the interface group tag. This can be used for example with *iptables*' [`devgroup`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#devgroup) match or *nftables*' *devgroup* type with `iifgroup` and `oifgroup` [meta expressions](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#META_EXPRESSIONS) to match any of the interfaces in the same group with a single rule which can simplify administration as long as there's a way to tag interfaces initially.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering kindly! I will give it a try by myself as well.

Comment: Do you mean one need to /etc/iproute2/group manually in order to tag by string like "blue"? And are there any kind of like official document for this topic? I do trust your answer but I just want to know how you got this info for when I get issues.

Comment: One doesn't need to change anything in /etc/iproute2. It's optional. I usually keep numbers only. The link comes from the iproute2 git repository. Feel free to check there. Or feel free to test if you can use blue instead of 1 by adding `1 blue`in the fle.

Comment: Also I put several links from the ip link man page about the group parameter.